# multiple textarea with same name and PHP treatment

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a dynamic form in which i can add and remove textarea.
The name of textareas is MyTextarea[]

```
<textarea style="display:inline;" name="MyTextarea[]"></textarea>
<textarea style="display:inline;" name="MyTextarea[]"></textarea>
```

So when I want to treat this textarea with PHP i'm doing a :

```
echo $_POST['MyTextarea'];
```

So a `Array` is display on the screen, up to now it's ok

So I do a `print_r($_POST['MyTextarea']);` and I have again the same result : `Array`

I want to know if it's possible to have many textarea with same name with `[]` to generate an array.

If it's possible how can I do, or what's wrong with my code.

Thanks

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, please add a sample of your HTML to the question. The way you describe this, the issue should not exist. I'm having doubts about the question, as `print_r($anything);` should *never* **only** print `Array`.

Comment: please provide us with whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which kind of framework are you using, I'm quite sure there is something at one point that is casting you're array into a string, maybe something that apply a treatment on POST variable like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($value && !$is_magic_quotes_gpc) {
        $_POST["$key"] = addslashes($value);
    }
```

In this case you've to remove this function...
To be sure of what I'm talking about, you can try a var_dump($POST[MyTextarea]) =>string 'Array' (length=5) (should be an array)

Comment: Yes actually when i'm dooing the `var_dump($_POST['MyTextarea']);`
I have string(5) "Array" 
So my array is cast in string, now I have to find why.

Comment: typically something is trying to remove quote from the array POST you're trying to pass, casting it into string...Have a close look to any function handling GET and POST parameter

Comment: It's OK
Actually in a file I have this code 

    $_POST = array_map("stripslashes", $_POST);

So with this code my array was cast in string.

Now it's work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in php if you have an input field with a name like this "MyTextarea[]" is posted as an array.

So if you want to access your data, you have to do:

```
echo $_POST['MyTextarea'][0];
```

If you have multiple textareas with the same name, you'll get an array where each index has one textarea. The first textarea in the form is the first textarea in the array

you could do

```
foreach ($_POST['MyTextarea'] as $textarea){
//do wat you need
}
```

This is obviously a killer feature to use if you need to add multiple textareas dinamically.

Comment: I try to do this but when I do :
echo $_POST['MyTextarea'][0]; 
This line display : A (the first char of Array)

And if I do 
foreach ($_POST['MyTextarea'] as $textarea){
     echo $textarea;
}

I have this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @guillaume - note the first line of the answer here: you need to specify emtpy array brackets in the field name in your HTML. ie `<textarea name='MyTextArea[]'>...</textarea>`

Comment: @Spudley: They don't have to be empty - you can explicitly index them.