# passing dynamic textboxes via javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a page where as the user can create dynamic textboxs that are resizable and draggable using jquery on the click of a button.

I want to pass the data in the textboxes plus the height width and position of them on the page from javascript to php.

I am at a bit of a block on this any help appreciated.

heres my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  {
    $posted=$_POST['textarea']; 
    echo "posted=".$new_post."<br>";
}
?>
<head>
<style>
      body{background-color:#ccc;}
      .dragbox{position:absolute;top:20px;width:320px; height:0;padding: 0.0em; margin:25px; border:0;cursor:move; z-index:1;display: block; }
      .textarea1{ width: 300px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em;}
      #handle{
          display: block; 
          height: 16px; 
          width: 100px; 
          background-color: red;
          position: relative;
          top:10px;
          font-size:10px;
          }
    </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="dynamic_div.php" method="post">
<script>        
    var i=0;    
    var p=75;
    function creatediv1(id) {
        id=id+i;
        var xp=xp+i;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
        newdiv.setAttribute('class', 'dragbox');
        newdiv.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');






     newdiv.style.position = "relative";
     newdiv.style.top = p;
     newdiv.style.cursor='move';
     newdiv.innerHTML = "<div id='handle'>Drag me into position</div></div><br><textarea id="+i +" name='textarea["+i+"]' class='textarea1' width='300' style='overflow-y: auto;background-color:transparent;border: 2px dashed #000; '>some text here</textarea>";


    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    $(function() {                      
        $( "#"+id ).draggable({                                 
         // Find position where image is dropped.
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                // Show dropped position.
                var Stoppos = $(this).position();
                $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
                alert("left="+Stoppos.left+"top="+Stoppos.top);
            }
        }); 

        $("#"+i).resizable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
            var width = ui.size.width;
            var height = ui.size.height;
            alert("width="+width+"height="+height);
            }
        });

        $("#"+i).draggable({handle:"#handle"});
    });  

    i++;
    p=p+25;
    }
    </script>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add New textbox" onclick="creatediv1('draggable');" />      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  >
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above discussion I understand that you are facing problem in getting the dynamically added Textboxes data in PHP, what I can suggest try using

```
<?php
print_r($_POST["textarea"]); //just for debugging
foreach ($_POST["textarea"] as $text_area) {
//do what you want with $text_area
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

from java script change

```
....
newdiv.innerHTML = "<div id='handle'>Drag me into position</div></div><br><textarea id="+i +" name='textarea[]' class='textarea1' width='300' style='overflow-y: auto;background-color:transparent;border: 2px dashed #000; '>some text here</textarea>";
```

and then try above php code.

**EDIT 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  {
    $posted=$_POST['textarea']; 
    echo "posted=".$new_post."<br>";
}
?>
<head>
<style>
      body{background-color:#ccc;}
      .dragbox{position:absolute;top:20px;width:320px; height:0;padding: 0.0em; margin:25px; border:0;cursor:move; z-index:1;display: block; }
      .textarea1{ width: 300px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em;}
      #handle{
          display: block; 
          height: 16px; 
          width: 100px; 
          background-color: red;
          position: relative;
          top:10px;
          font-size:10px;
          }
    </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="dynamic_div.php" method="post">
<script>        
    var i=0;    
    var p=75;
    function creatediv1(id)
    {
        id=id+i;
        var xp=xp+i;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
        newdiv.setAttribute('class', 'dragbox');
        newdiv.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
        newdiv.style.position = "relative";
        newdiv.style.top = p;
        newdiv.style.cursor='move';
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<div id='handle'>Drag me into position</div></div><br><textarea id="+i +" name='textarea[]' class='textarea1' width='300' style='overflow-y: auto;background-color:transparent;border: 2px dashed #000; '>some text here</textarea>";

        //Updated this line
        document.getElementById("frmMain").appendChild(newdiv);
        $(function()
        {
            $( "#"+id ).draggable(
            {
                stop: function(event, ui)
                {
                    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
                    $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
                    $('.textarea1').append("left="+Stoppos.left+"top="+Stoppos.top);
                }
            }); 

            $("#"+i).resizable(
            {
                stop: function(event, ui)
                {
                    var width = ui.size.width;
                    var height = ui.size.height;
                    $('.textarea1').append("width="+width+"height="+height);
                }
            });

            $("#"+i).draggable({handle:"#handle"});
        });  

        i++;
        p=p+25;
    }
    </script>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add New textbox" onclick="creatediv1('draggable');" />      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  >
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BarryWatts, means you are not getting any thing in `print_r`? If it is so, then try to assign name to your dynamic text areas from java script, like `my_text_area[]`, **DON'T** forget the last two `[]`, and from php try `print_r($_POST[my_text_area]);` or simply from you code change `name='textarea["+i+"]'` to `name='textarea[]'` and try the above code.

Comment: yes tried this and still returns nothing, I have tried var_dump($_POST['textarea']); and that returns NULL

Comment: by doing a alert(document.body.outerHTML); in the draggable I can see that the textareas are outside of the form. How do I get them to fall within the form

Comment: @BarryWatts, see my above **EDIT 1**

Comment: Ummar that works great but I dont want the boxes appended with the size and position how can I pass size and position as a $_POST

Comment: You can try to put the position and size in some hidden variables of form, and as soon as item is dropped that hidden field should be updated, when you will post the form you will get the size and position in same way in `POST` variable.

Answer (score 0):

In this `$( "#"+id ).draggable({`  code you will get `undefined id error` because `var id` is not in Global scope.

and second you will never get value of id if you set it in Global because `creatediv1` function set `ID` value but it will execute when html is fully loaded where as `document.ready` code will execute when html gets loaded so `ID` value will always comes up with error,

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  {
    $posted=$_POST['textarea']; 
    echo "posted=".$new_post."<br>";
}
?>
<head>
<style>
      body{background-color:#ccc;}
      .dragbox{position:absolute;top:20px;width:320px; height:0;padding: 0.0em; margin:25px; border:0;cursor:move; z-index:1;display: block; }
      .textarea1{ width: 300px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em;}
      #handle{
          display: block; 
          height: 16px; 
          width: 100px; 
          background-color: red;
          position: relative;
          top:10px;
          font-size:10px;
          }
    </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="dynamic_div.php" method="post">
<script>        
    var i=0;    
    var p=75;
    function creatediv1(id)
    {
        id=id+i;
        var xp=xp+i;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
        newdiv.setAttribute('class', 'dragbox');
        newdiv.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
        newdiv.style.position = "relative";
        newdiv.style.top = p;
        newdiv.style.cursor='move';
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<div id='handle'>Drag me into position</div></div><br><textarea id="+i +" name='textarea["+i+"]' class='textarea1' width='300' style='overflow-y: auto;background-color:transparent;border: 2px dashed #000; '>some text here</textarea>";

        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
        $(function()
        {
            $( "#"+id ).draggable(
            {
                stop: function(event, ui)
                {
                    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
                    $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
                    $('.textarea1').append("left="+Stoppos.left+"top="+Stoppos.top);
                }
            }); 

            $("#"+i).resizable(
            {
                stop: function(event, ui)
                {
                    var width = ui.size.width;
                    var height = ui.size.height;
                    $('.textarea1').append("width="+width+"height="+height);
                }
            });

            $("#"+i).draggable({handle:"#handle"});
        });  

        i++;
        p=p+25;
    }
    </script>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Add New textbox" onclick="creatediv1('draggable');" />      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  >
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors the "$( "#"+id ).draggable({" is working fine in all browsers

Comment: You will have to excuse my lack of javascript knowledge I am just using snippets of code That I have found around the web and tried to make them work together. All is working and if I do a javascript call so show the page data it shows the textboxes added with names of textarea[0], textarea[1]..., I just can't seem to find a way of passing this to a php script via a $_post

Comment: Hi this passes the details to the textboxes. I want the data passed via a $_post so I can manipulate it via php

Comment: sure you can do that but you need to find a way to access array of posted textarea data because its creating textarea array in html thats it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520667/multiple-textarea-with-same-name-and-php-treatment

Comment: Dipesh, I have tried the help from that post but it still returns nothing

Comment: by doing a alert(document.body.outerHTML); in the draggable I can see that the textareas are outside of the form. How do I get them to fall within the form

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
name='textarea[]'

<?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST["textarea"]); //just for debugging
   echo "<pre>";

   for($i=0; $i<count($_POST["textarea"]);$i++) {
     //$_POST["textarea"][i] ...

   }
?>
```

Comment: hi this also returns nothing. I have tried var_dump($_POST['textarea']); and that returns NULL

Comment: by doing a alert(document.body.outerHTML); in the draggable I can see that the textareas are outside of the form. How do I get them to fall within the form