# pass values of textboxes of the same name to jquery and then to php page for storing the values to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a list of textboxes as follows :

```
` <table id="div1" style="width:100%;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Question Text</label>
            </td>
                <td colspan="5">        
                <textarea rows="4" cols="500" name="questiontext" id="questiontext" > <?php print $view->questions->getQuestion_Text() ?></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td> <label>Option a) </label></td>
                        <td colspan="5"> <textarea rows="1" cols="200" name="Optiontext[]" id="text1"> </textarea> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <label> Option b) </label></td>
                        <td colspan="5"> <textarea rows="1" cols="200" name="Optiontext[]" id="text2"> </textarea> </td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
 </table>`
```

I need to pass the values to a jquery function as follows :

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#question').live('submit',function(){
            var params={};
            params.action='saveQuestion';
            params.questionid=$('#questionid').val();
            params.questiontext=$('#questiontext').val();
            return false;
        })
});
```

My question is how do i pass the values of the textarea to the jquery function as textarea can be dynamically created.

I tried to access the values of textarea directly in php as follows but the values are not passed:

```
            $option_key = 1;
            for($i = 0;$i<= count($_POST['Optiontext']);$i++){
                 $option = $_POST['Optiontext'][$i];
                 if(isset($option))
                    {               
                        $query_options="INSERT INTO `XXX`(`Question_ID`, `Option_Key`, `Option_Value`) VALUES ($max_id,'$option_key','$option')";   
                        $sql = mysql_query($query_options)or die($query_options."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
                        $option_key = $option_key + 1;  
                    }
               }// for loop ends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass the value of textboxes by map function as follows

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#question').live('submit',function(){
        var params={};
        params.action='saveQuestion';
        params.questionid=$('#questionid').val();
        params.questiontext=$('#questiontext').val();
        var Optiontext = [];
        Optiontext = $('textarea[name^="Optiontext\\["]').map(function() {
                      var value_textarea = $(this).val();
                    if(value_textarea && value_textarea != ' ')
                      { 
                            return $(this).val();   
                      }

        }).get();
          params.Optiontext=Optiontext;


        return false;
    }) });
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of each textarea are posted to the form as a comma-delimited variable called 'Optiontext[]'. 
Since commas can be added in the textareas, it could get interesting trying to split the data back into the correct fields!  Possibly a better solution would be a finite number of textarea fields with unique names, or dynamically create them as needed using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Also, see answers for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520667/multiple-textarea-with-same-name-and-php-treatment